# How do I sort a mulidimensional array in php by the keys?

Tags: php

I know this question has been asked several times but the answers given don't help my situation.

I have a simple array that basically represent the month and year. The only purpose of the array is to keep track of events in a database and I need to know which months and years are represented. The array is basically:

```
$array[MONTH][YEAR] = 1; //just any value. Don't care about the value.
```

I need to sort the array so that the years are in order but also any months in the same year should also be sorted. See the output I want below...

```
$dates[10][2012] = 1;
$dates[1][2011] = 1;
$dates[12][2013] = 1;
$dates[4][2010] = 1;
$dates[6][2009] = 1;
$dates[7][2009] = 1;
```

How do I sort this array so that the values come back as:

```
Array
(
    [6] => Array
    (
        [2009] => 1
    )
    [7] => Array
    (
        [2009] => 1
    )
    [4] => Array
    (
        [2010] => 1
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [2011] => 1
    )
    [10] => Array
    (
        [2012] => 1
    )
    [12] => Array
    (
        [2013] => 1
    )
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: either way, how do I sort it by YEAR, then month?

Comment: I've updated my answer below to show how you would sort it if you changed the index order. I assumed you were locked into that order, but if you can change it to `[YEAR][MONTH]` instead it's really a lot simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [uasort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php). You can write a custom function to sort on the inner keys rather than the outer ones.

***EDIT:***

It turns out that you need to use [uksort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) if you want to sort the outer months as well. This seems to work:

```
uksort($dates, function ($a, $b) use ($dates) {
  $year = key($dates[$a]) - key($dates[$b]);
  $month = $a - $b;
  return $year == 0 ? $month : $year;
});
```

***EDIT:***

If you just change the index order like Jon suggested above it's a lot simpler:

```
$dates[2012][10] = 1;
$dates[2011][1] = 1;
$dates[2013][12] = 1;
$dates[2010][4] = 1;
$dates[2009][7] = 1;
$dates[2009][6] = 1;

ksort($dates);
array_walk($dates, ksort);

print_r($dates);
```

Comment: That is actually `uksort` for sorting by key

Comment: If I could figure out how to use these sort functions on this issue, I would have it made. Got an example of what you are talking about Hameed?

Comment: @Hameed - I was thinking that we only needed to sort the keys on the inner arrays and could ignore the outer ones. I've edited my answer and added an example using `uksort` instead.

Comment: Very close. The months are not in order; Here is what I got:

    $dates[2012][9] = 1;
    $dates[2012][8] = 1;

    // run your routine

    Array
(
    [2012] => Array
        (
            [9] => 1
            [8] => 1
        )

)

Comment: @pogeybait - You're totally right. I didn't realize the months were already in order in the input. Apparently `array_map` wasn't doing what I thought it did. I've swapped it for `array_walk` and now it works as you'd expect.